# Google Pay works only when NFC is being turned on

Tags: nfc, google-pay

I got S23+ last week and am having problems with Google Pay. When I put the phone to the terminal, nothing happens (NFC is on). After some trial and error, it turns out it works fine but only in the moment when I turn NFC on. AKA I hold the phone to the terminal, NFC is OFF, I turn NFC on and the payment processes. Next payment I have to turn NFC off, and on again while the phone is at the terminal.

Any ideas?